# Problem in discourse while vBulletin import

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on vBulletin to Discourse converting.
Everything works well, but when I running this script :

`bundle exec ruby script/import_scripts/vbulletin.rb`

I got this error :

```
...
7: from /var/www/discourse/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.3.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:666:in `load_config_initializer'
         6: from /var/www/discourse/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.3.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:208:in `instrument'
         5: from /var/www/discourse/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.3.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:667:in `block in load_config_initializer'
         4: from /var/www/discourse/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-7.0.3.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:667:in `load'
         3: from /var/www/discourse/config/initializers/006-mini_profiler.rb:89:in `<main>'
         2: from /var/www/discourse/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rack-mini-profiler-3.0.0/lib/mini_profiler/profiling_methods.rb:65:in `counter_method'
         1: from /var/www/discourse/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rack-mini-profiler-3.0.0/lib/mini_profiler/profiling_methods.rb:85:in `profile_method'
/var/www/discourse/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rack-mini-profiler-3.0.0/lib/mini_profiler/profiling_methods.rb:85:in `alias_method': undefined method `call' for class `Redis::Client' (NameError)
Did you mean?  caller
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you need to install and run Redis.

Here you can find the list of dependencies: 
https://github.com/discourse/discourse